Dual boot Debian Trixie and Windows 11 causes heating issue on Framework 16 Laptop
Recently purchased a Framework 16 Laptop with an expansion GPU. CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7940HS GPU: AMD Radeon RX 7700S and AMD Radeon 780M
I received the laptop with Windows already installed and I installed Debian Trixie as a dual boot partition. Disk 1 100MB EFI Disk 2 1.5 GB recovery Disk 3 292 GB Debain Disk 4 1GB Swap Disk 5 660 GB windows
I was loaded into the windows partition and was playing Pacific Drive and it caused my cpu to spike to 100% and both CPU and GPU temps were over 100C.
Same thing occurred with Cinebench. I submitted a helpdesk ticket and received a new motherboard after their troubleshooting. When I replaced the motherboard grub was removed and it booted immediately into windows. I tested by running Pacific Drive again and everything was running normal and was running at around 20% CPU and GPU and CPU were running at around 80C.
I reinstalled GRUB using a USB and repair function and can now boot into grub and either partition however when I started up Pacific Drive again CPU and GPU spike up again to 100C.
Why would reinstalling grub cause this to occur?

Though you did observe a change, I don't see how grub itself could be the cause -- after Windows boots from grub menu, grub is not running. Could be the installation causes some other issue (e.g., installing a coin miner). How did you make the installation? Have you tried another OS?

I have tried the game and throttle testing on linux alone and it appeared to be working at 90C which I believe is normal. It only occurs on windows but only after grub was reinstalled which I found weird.

This may have something to do with the firmware (microcode) for the CPU not being loaded correctly, which usually happens during boot, but that is a shot in the dark. I don't use Windows; is it possible to read out the CPU firmware version that is running?
